# merge 2D array of 2D arrays into 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array of 2D arrays `t`, which can be emulated by this code:

```
import numpy as np

n=3
x = np.random.randint(0,10, (n,1))
y = np.random.randint(0,10, (n,2))

t = np.empty((2,2), object)
t[0,:] = [x,y]
t[1,:] = [x+10,y+10]
```

How can I merge the `t` into a single array of size (6,3) like this:

```
np.vstack([np.hstack([x,y]), np.hstack([x,y])+10])
```

Comment: This question is ambiguous. There is more than one way to convert this array into an array with dimensions of (6,3). Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: Added a sample above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One sequence that works:

```
In [88]: [np.hstack(row) for row in t]
Out[88]: 
[array([[3, 9, 9],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [0, 6, 3]]),
 array([[13, 19, 19],
        [11, 11, 10],
        [10, 16, 13]])]

In [89]: np.concatenate([np.hstack(row) for row in t], axis=0)
Out[89]: 
array([[ 3,  9,  9],
       [ 1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  3],
       [13, 19, 19],
       [11, 11, 10],
       [10, 16, 13]])

In [100]: np.block(t.tolist())
Out[100]: 
array([[ 3,  9,  9],
       [ 1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  3],
       [13, 19, 19],
       [11, 11, 10],
       [10, 16, 13]])
```

Comment: Why using concatenate directly on `t` fails?

Comment: `np.concatenate(t,0)` is effectively `np.concatenate(list(t), 0)`, which just recreates `t`.  `concatenate/hstack/vstack/stack` work best on a 1d array of arrays.  But `t.ravel()` is a list of differing arrays, 1 and 2 column.  The fact that you had to use that 'fillin' an object dtype array constructor, shows that your arangement is nonstandard, and needs some special steps.

Comment: Just remembered that `np.block` can do that nested sequence of v/hstack for you.  No faster, just one call.

Comment: Can you show a line of how to use it on t?

Comment: Added, `block` wants a list of lists